# Error git clone git@github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Tags: raspbian, node.js, mysql, debug

I would like to seek help on `npm install felixge/node-mysql`. I been trying to install mysql into Raspberry PI so that I can do node.js with mySQL for my REST API but this problems been there for 2 days and I'm totally lost now.

**This is the npm-debug.log:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'felixge/node-mysql' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.14
3 info using node@v0.10.29
4 verbose cache add [ 'felixge/node-mysql', null ]
5 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="felixge/node-mysql" args=["felixge/node-mysql",null]
6 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
6 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
6 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
6 verbose parsed url   host: null,
6 verbose parsed url   port: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
6 verbose parsed url   search: null,
6 verbose parsed url   query: null,
6 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'felixge/node-mysql',
6 verbose parsed url   path: 'felixge/node-mysql',
6 verbose parsed url   href: 'felixge/node-mysql' }
7 silly lockFile 4f4f7be1-felixge-node-mysql felixge/node-mysql
8 verbose lock felixge/node-mysql /var/www/.npm/4f4f7be1-felixge-node-mysql.lock
9 info maybeGithub Attempting felixge/node-mysql from git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
10 silly lockFile a6c4cfee-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
11 verbose lock git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql /var/www/.npm/a6c4cfee-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql.lock
12 verbose addRemoteGit [ 'git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql', 'master' ]
13 verbose git clone git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql Cloning into bare repository '/var/www/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-felixge-node-mysql-a6c4cfee'...
13 verbose git clone git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
13 verbose git clone git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
13 verbose git clone git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection refused
14 silly lockFile a6c4cfee-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
15 silly lockFile a6c4cfee-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
16 info maybeGithub Attempting felixge/node-mysql from git+ssh://git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql
17 silly lockFile 246b2140-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql
18 verbose lock git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql /var/www/.npm/246b2140-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql.lock
19 verbose addRemoteGit [ 'git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql', 'master' ]
20 error git clone git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql Cloning into bare repository '/var/www/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-felixge-node-mysql-246b2140'...
20 error git clone git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql
20 error git clone git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
20 error git clone git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
21 silly lockFile 246b2140-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql
22 silly lockFile 246b2140-it-github-com-felixge-node-mysql git@github.com:felixge/node-mysql
23 silly lockFile 4f4f7be1-felixge-node-mysql felixge/node-mysql
24 silly lockFile 4f4f7be1-felixge-node-mysql felixge/node-mysql
25 error addLocal Could not install felixge/node-mysql
26 error Error: ENOENT, stat 'felixge/node-mysql'
27 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
27 error including the npm and node versions, at:
27 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
28 error System Linux 3.12.25+
29 error command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "felixge/node-mysql"
30 error cwd /var/www
31 error node -v v0.10.29
32 error npm -v 1.4.14
33 error path felixge/node-mysql
34 error code ENOENT
35 error errno 34
36 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

**This is the screenshot:**
[image]

Hope you guys could help me out with it as soon as possible, thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: are you running as superuser e.g. `sudo`?

Comment: I have and can't works too, Phil Vallone.

Comment: Why don't you follow the on-screen instructions from the developer? Report the error on Github with the log file.